# At what point in the Wheel of Time do we find out who killed a certain Forsaken?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, robert-jordan

Sorry about the ambiguous title, but I want to prevent spoilers.  Read no further if you haven't read through at least *The Fires of Heaven* in Robert Jordan's *Wheel of Time* series.

> At the end of the 5th book of *The Wheel of Time*, *The Fires of Heaven*, Asmodean is killed by an unknown figure right after a shock of recognition.

At what point in the series do we find out who the killer is, and at what point in the series should we have gathered enough clues to figure it out on our own?

Note that I'm not looking for the identity of the killer (if that's even known yet).  If you know who it is, please use [spoiler text](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As far as I remember, RJ mentioned at some point that we should have been able to figure it out. However, it wasn't until Towers of Midnight that the community reached a general consensus as to who did it. In the book, we're never actually told "so and so killed so and so", but there is evidence in the book that helps narrow it down, and I believe BS confirmed to the community that their conclusion was correct.

So, short answer is Towers of Midnight.

If you're looking for details about who did it and how we find it out, [this](http://www.dragonmount.com/forums/topic/55636-asmodeans-killer/page__st__20__p__1741818__hl__asmodean__fromsearch__1#entry1741818) forum post should help clarify things (scroll down to the very last post on the page, obviously contains spoilers)

Comment: To correct shadowfission's answer (I can't comment on answers yet >:( ) The identity is revealed in Towers of Midnight. It is explicitly stated in the glossary at the end of the book.

Comment: There are two ways that it's made clear in ToM - It's stated straight out in the glossary entry for the killer, and there's a point where one of the Forsaken says to the killer - you've been involved in the deaths of X Chosen, and X is one greater than we knew about.

Answer (score 4):

I've read them all but unfortunately I can't remember whether we've found that out yet. If you've read the whole series it may be worth your while visiting the Tor website where there's a commentary by Leigh Butler (who used to maintain the Wheel of Time FAQ: http://linuxmafia.com/jordan/ ) of her re-read of the whole series which contains all of the major plot developments as they occur.

You can find the re-read detailed here: http://www.tor.com/blogs/2009/02/wheel-of-time-re-read-index but the suggestion is that you shouldn't read it unless you've read all of the books as even the discussion of the early books contains major plot spoilers from later in the series.